# How can I plot x sin^2[1/x] on [Pi/4,Pi]?

Tags: plotting

And I want this plot to be discrete into 100 equal rectangulars which topmid of them have a line joined together.

Something like this, but for the mentioned equation:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the option `Joined -> True` in `DiscretePlot`:

```
DiscretePlot[x Sin[1/x]^2, {x, π/4, π, π/80}, 
 PlotStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thin, Gray}], 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ExtentSize -> Full, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) For large step sizes or unwieldy functions, the `Joined` option might not be sufficient, depending on your application.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to combine stylized outputs from `DiscretePlot` and `Plot`:

```
Show[
  DiscretePlot[
    x Sin[1/x]^2, 
    {x, π/4, π, π/80}, 
    BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.75], GrayLevel[0.25]]],
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
    ExtentSize -> Full, 
    PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.75]
  ],
  Plot[
    x Sin[1/x]^2, 
    {x, π/4, π}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.75], Black]
  ]
]
```

[image]